# Access to folders on Ubuntu-based Rails server (keep getting "No such file..")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ffmpeg

I am setting up Rails+ffmpeg on Ubuntu and I keep getting

```
 Errno::ENOENT
 No such file or directory..
```

The setup is as follows:

/home/username/RailsApp
/home/username/videos/

I am trying to run ffmpeg to write to /home/username/videos and I used "/home/username/videos/" and "~/videos/" but no luck..

What am I missing?

"www-data" user is included in "username" group..

Rails app works fine otherwise..

Any input greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally is good not to be dependent on local file system. Try following:

```
path_to_video = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/videos/video1.avi"
print File.exist?(path_to_video)
```

If you don't want to have videos in `Rails/public` just create a link with `ln -s target link_name` and on production server you should do it in similar way e.g. with capistrano.

Btw. what are the rights to videos? `-rw-r--r--`? and under wich user is running your webserver?

Comment: the user is 'www-data' who is included in 'username' group, which is /home/username/  - is that good practice? Thanks for the Rails tip! Will use that, also figured the problem was due to the fact that I cannot use '~/videos' as a path...